# How to make normal html Email Template to Responsive(w.r.t all the screen i.e.,PC,Ipad and Mobile) Email Template for the below code

Tags: css, html

Below is the code which i have written and please help me out in making that as responsive :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><!--supports all Unicode characters in our document-->
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> <!--Windows Phones will display our mobile version correctly-->
<!--<![endif]-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" /> -->
<style>
/* Basics */
body {
margin: 0 !important;  /*  used for avoiding spaces and align from top */
padding: 0;
background-color: #3C3C3C;
}
table {
border-spacing: 0; /* to avoid spacing to borders */
font-family: sans-serif;
color: #333333;
}
td {
padding: 0;
}
img {
border: 0;
}
div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] { 
margin:0 !important;
}
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;/* to prevent the iPhone and iPad from inflating some fonts*/
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.webkit {
max-width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color:#FFFFFF; 
}
.outer {
Margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 600px;
}
.full-width-image img {
width: 100%;
max-width: 600px;
height: auto;
}
.full-width-image h1{
margin: 0 auto;
font-size:22px;
border-bottom:3px solid #919191;
color:#3C3C3C;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
.inner {
padding: 10px;
}
p {
Margin: 0;
}
.h1 {
font-size: 21px;
font-weight: bold;
Margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.h2 {
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
Margin-bottom: 12px;
}

/* One column layout */
.one-column .contents {
text-align: left;
}
.one-column p {
padding:10px 0px 5px 5px;
color:#15717D;
font-size:20px;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
}
.two-column{
background-color:#F36533;
padding:15px 0px 10px 35px;
}

.text1{
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:22px;
font-family:sans-serif;
}
.text2{
color:#FFFFFF;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
}
.col-text{
padding-left:15px;
padding-top:10px;
font-size:16px;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
color:#15717D;
}
.safety-text p{
font-size:21px;
font-weight:bold;
padding: 25px 0 25px 15px;
line-height:26px;
}
.safety-text span{
font-size:14px;
font-weight:lighter;
}
.safety-text a{
font-weight:bold;
color:#3C3C3C;
}
.brand-text{
padding:8px 0px 40px 15px;
font-size:30px;
color:#6FFEEC; 
text-shadow:-2px -2px 0 #000,2px -2px 0 #000,-2px 2px 0 #000,2px 2px 0 #000;
}
.box-content p{
padding:20px 135px 5px 10px;
background-color:#000000;
<!-- width:420px; -->
}
.register-button{
background-color:#000000;
padding: 15px 0px 20px 10px;    
}
.register-button p {
color:#15717D;
border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
border-radius:30px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
width:220px;
text-align:center;
padding: 15px;
}
.indication-text p{
font-size: 20px;
width: 560px;
color:#72635C;
}
.indication-text{
padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;
line-height:2em;    
}
.speakers-text{
padding:0 0 0 20px;
}
.list-items{
font-size: 20px;
color:#72635C;
font-weight:bold;
list-style:none;
}
li::before {
content: "•";
color: #F16532
 }
.speaker-details1{
vertical-align:top;
padding-left: 15px;
}
.speaker-details2{
vertical-align:top;
padding-left: 15px;
}
.speaker-details2 h2{
color:#72635C;
}
.speaker-details2 p{
color:#FFFFFF;
border:1px solid #FFFFFF;
border-radius:30px;
background-color:#15717D;
width:220px;
text-align:center;
padding: 15px;
}
.bottom-text{
padding:15px 0 40px 10px;
}
.bottom-text p{
font-size: 19px;
color:#72635C;
}
.bottom-text a {
color:#72635C;
}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<center class="wrapper">
<div class="webkit">
<table class="outer" align="center">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="column">
            <table class="outer" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="full-width-image">
                        <h1>Main Heading Goes here for the following template</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="one-column">
        <div class="column">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="inner contents">
                        <p>From:<br>
                        TO:<br>
                        Date:<br>
                        Subject:<br>
                        [Pre header]
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="two-column">
        <div class="column">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="two-column-img">
                        <img src="images/gsk-logo.png" alt="gsk" style="width:80px;height:55px;"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text1">
                        For HealthCare Professionals
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="text2">
                    <p style="font-size:12px;font-family:sans-serif;"><u>[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.]</u></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="information-column">
        <div class="column">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-text">
                        <u>Prescribing Information</u></p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-text">
                        <u>[Patient Information Leaflet]</u>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="safety-text">
                        <p>
                        Important Safety Information<br>
                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur,sed to euismod temper incididunt<br>ut labore et dolore magna aquila.<a>Continued Below</a></span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="one-column"> 
        <div class="column">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="brand-text">
                        [BRAND LOGO,GENERIC,STRENGTHS]
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="one-column">  
        <div class="column">
            <table width="90%" style="margin-left:10px;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="box-content">
                        <p style="color:#FFFFFF;">You're invited to:</p>
                        <p style="color:#FFFFFF;">[Title,Speaker First name Last name] <br>[Work Area]</p>
                        <p style="color:#FFFFFF;">[Date] | [Time] | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Website</p> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="register-button">
                    <p>Register for Website</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="indication"> 
        <div class="column">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="indication-text">
                        <h2>Indication</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="indication"> 
        <div class="column">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="indication-text">
                        <h2>[Greeting Salutation]</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="indication">  
        <div class="column">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="indication-text">
                    <h2>[List of Website Listings]</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <ul class="list-items">
                        <li>
                        Unordered list item
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        Unordered list item
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="speakers-text">
    <h2>Speakers</h2>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="speakers-list">
        <div class="column">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="inner">
                        <table class="contents">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="images/img1.png" width="270" height="185" alt="" />
                                </td>
                                <td class="speaker-details1" align="top">
                                    <h3>[Follow MI template for speaker bio]</h3>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="speakers-list">
        <div class="column">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="inner">
                        <table class="contents">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="images/img2.png" width="270" height="185" alt="" />
                                </td>
                                <td class="speaker-details2">
                                    <h3>[Follow MI template for speaker bio]</h3>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" class="full-text"> 
                                <h2>[Full Important Safety Information]</h2>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="speakers-list">
        <div class="column">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="inner" style="border-top:5px solid #F36533;">
                        <table class="contents">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="images/img3.png" width="270" height="185" alt="" />
                                </td>
                                <td class="speaker-details2">
                                    <h2>[Join and Speaker name text.]</h2>
                                    <p>Register for Website</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bottom-text">
                        <p>Please see full <u>Prescribing information</u>,including <u>[Patient Information Leaflet]</u>, for [PRODUCT(Generic)]</p><br>
                        <p>This email is intented for US healthcare professionals only.</p><br>
                        <p>To report SUSPECTED ADVERSE REACTIONS, contact MadhuriChiluka at 1-835-965-1254 of FAD at 1-756-FAD-8475 or <a>www.fad.div/telecomh</a>.</p><br>
                        <p>[PRODUCT] is a registered trademark of ABC.</p><br>
                        <p><u>[ABC LOGO]</u> &copy; [YYYY] ABC group of companies.All rights reserved.Produced in INDIA.[Activity ID][Month YYYY]</p><br>
                        <p>Do not reply to this e-mail.Replies sent to this e-mail address are not received.</p><br>
                        <p>[MadhuriChiluka Response Center, P.O.Box 201, 1 Mreoo Dr.,Researchpark Park, NC 58794]</p><br>
                        <p>[If you are not interested in receiving further e-mail communications like this one,or if you received this message in error,please visit <a>www.contactus.abc.com/genius.html</a>]</p><br>
                        <p>[Third Party mailing address and 125-YGOO statment]</p><br>
                        <p><u>[Privacy Statement]</u></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to add some files i think.

Comment: Nope, it consists of only one html page in which css will also be included in it.

Comment: You can use  MJML technique for responsive email template here is the link
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/01/making-responsive-html-email-coding-easy-with-mjml/

Comment: okay thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

I think you must learn the CSS responsive stuff.
And then try it out, if you stuck on something then come back.

http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/

Br Christoph